# Experience replay in Q-learning explodes

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I implemented Q-learning in the game of Tron and this is working perfectly. However, I want to implement experience replay as to see how this works. This is wat I do:

1. I store the current state, the action taken, the reward, and the highest Q-value in the next state.
2. After a given number of games I sample randomly from the experiences (10%,50% or 100%) and then recalculate the input values using the current state.
   (I am unsure whether this is correct, therefore I also tried to save the activation values and just reinstate them to make it really off-policy).
3. Then I use back-propagation.

However, my Q-values explode to either inf or -inf by doing this. When I test the same code directly after each move, so I save everything in the same way and back-propagate after each action then it learns perfectly.

Does anyone have a clue how this can happen? It seems as if experience replay causes my Q-values to become extremely large or small.

Comment: You should store tuples (s,a,r,s'), without the Q-value. When you sample from memory, you recompute the Q-value according to your current network.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the problem! Do you have a clue why with my wrong implementation it led to extremely large or small Q-values?

Comment: Happy to hear that you solved the problem :)
My guess is that the network loss was extremely high, due to the use of very old Q-values, and therefore the gradient exploded.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!